# Web API for .Net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is Web API available for .Net 3.5 SP1? The SP1 does include System.Web.Routing assembly so I guess it should be available for SP1 too. I downloaded the Web API from:

http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP

and downloaded "Preview 1" (the oldest one) but didn't managed to compile the source. I am stuck in .Net SP1 in one project and I need this API. Has anybody managed to use Web API in 3.5 SP1 project? Or do I rely on using WCF webHttpBinding only?

Comment: closest thing I would advise is to create a selfhosted wcf service using the webhttpbinding to provide you with that rest-ish experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebAPI requires .net 4.  You can't use it on .net 3.5 (sp1 or not).

You also can't use the preview releases for production code as you don't have a "go-live" license, so even if you could get it to work, it wouldn't be legal.  You need to use at least the ASP.NET WebAPI Beta to get a go-live license.