# ASP.NET Web API HttpClient on 3.5 or 2.0 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I like the HttpClient in ASP.NET Web API. Can I use it in 3.5 or 2.0. I mean in any .NET Framework application versions before 4.0. Actually, I have a ASP.NET Web API app in ASP.NET 4.0. I need to consume this app from a device built in 3.5 framework. I know I can use WebClient/WebRequest, But It will be great If I can use HttpClient stuffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9643714/985284),

> WebAPI requires .net 4. You can't use it on .net 3.5 (sp1 or not).
>
> You also can't use the preview releases for production code as you
>   don't have a "go-live" license, so even if you could get it to work,
>   it wouldn't be legal. You need to use at least the ASP.NET WebAPI Beta
>   to get a go-live license.

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8257652/985284),

> The HttpClient library was initially introduced in the "[WCF REST
>   Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest)" project, so you can download it from there. This project
>   isn't supported anymore (most of its functionality has either made it
>   into the framework or is now part of the Web API project), but the
>   HttpClient from there works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your HttpClient project should be completely separate from your service project. I would keep the service(s) project as it is in 2.0 or 3.5 and create a 4.0 project with HttpClient and make HTTP calls.

The only minor issue here is implicit model binding. Here you can use a Model dll or consume the 3.5 model classes in the 4.0 client project. But the JsonObject binding should also work seamlessly for json resonses.